# Grails App deployment on Micro Cloud Foundry

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I tried to deploy a simple hello world application on Micro Cloud Foundry. I went through the process that mentioned in video and set up every thing (My IDE is STS eclipse and Windows 7). When I wanted to make a server on Micro Cloud Foundry: 1) I could not set my server host name to my domain for example "multisite.cloudfoundry.me" it said "The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts" and forced me to put "localhost" as the server name. 2) When I went through the process it started my Grails application and seemed it was running well but the url was broken "http://12431asd.multisite.cloudfoundry.me/" (It asked me for Grails app on this domain I choose "12431asd") and I got the message "VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND". when I tried this url "http://api.multisite.cloudfoundry.me/" I get the message "Welcome to VMware's Cloud Application Platform".

I appreciate any help and suggestions.
Reza

Answer (score 1):

When you add a CloudFoundry server leave the first pane with the default settings and then on the second pane select the "Microcloud" url option setting the name to "multisite" in the popup dialog. Once the plugin has contacted your instance you can go ahead and put the email and the password in.

From there you should just be able to deploy by dragging the application to the server instance in your servers tab, setting the url in the dialog that follows. Once deployed you can double-click the application instance in the server tab and adjust its properties.

Can you verify that when you deployed the application, it's state was started? (it should say next to the application name under the server)

Comment: Thanks Dan, yes it is stared and it seems everything is running [started] but the URL does not work.